# Angular Material Autocomplete - Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Tags: angular-material, angular6

I'm trying to wire the Angular Material autocomplete and get the error below.

> core.js:1673 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
>       at ProgramsComponent.push../src/app/programs/programs.component.ts.ProgramsComponent._filter (programs.component.ts:34)

Here is the code:

program.component.ts

```
import { ProgramService } from './../program.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-programs',
  templateUrl: './programs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./programs.component.css']
})
export class ProgramsComponent implements OnInit {
  programNamesControl = new FormControl();
  programNames: string[];
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

  constructor(private programService: ProgramService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.programService.getProgramNames().subscribe(data => {
      this.programNames = data;
    });

    this.filteredOptions = this.programNamesControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this._filter(value))
    );
  }

  _filter(value: string): string[] {
    console.log('Inside filter..');
    return this.programNames.filter(programName =>
      programName.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
    );
  }
}
```

program.component.html

```
<form>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" placeholder="ProgramName" aria-label="ProgramName"
      matInput [formControl]="programNamesControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
          {{option}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Comment: So, `this.programNames` is probably `undefined` when you try to call it in `_filter()`. You can protect the code for that situation.

Comment: You’re right. In the constructor, do I do something like this.ProgramNames = {};

Comment: There are various solutions. You can declare it as: `programNames: string[] = [];`. Or you can set a default value in the constructor. Or you can test if it is defined in `_filter()` and return an empty array if it is.

Comment: How do I code the last one?  Test if programNames is defined in _filter() and return an empty array if it is.  Is setting a default value in the constructor done like this - this.ProgramName = {};

Comment: Solution (3): `return this.programNames ? this.programNames.filter(...) : [];`

Comment: Solution (2): `this.programNames = [];`

Comment: programNames: string[]=[]; you also do like this